# C++ Bulid Error "undefined" for dacap/clip when using MinGW g++ 8.3.0

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debugging, cmake

I'm trying to debug a C++ program in VSCode, using the [microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/debug-launch.md) extension, but I get an error while the build step.

**Reproduction Steps:**

1. Clone a library I need to use. `git submodule add https://github.com/dacap/clip.git clip` on the project directory, let's say `C:\pg\cpp_dev_02`
2. Create `CMakeLists.txt` (the content below), as documented on [Home · dacap/clip Wiki](https://github.com/dacap/clip/wiki) (the cmake configuration output log below)
3. Click `debug` on the CMake menu to try to start debugging
4. Fails with an error (the cmake build output log below / the screenshot below)

That's all about the issue I have.

By the way building with cmake outside of VSCode passes.

```
cd C:\pg\cpp_dev_03\; mkdir build; cd build;
cmake ..
cmake --build . --config Release
C:\pg\cpp_dev_03\build\Release\myproject.exe
echo $? # True
```

Just in case the versions:

```
> g++ --version
g++.exe (x86_64-posix-seh, Built by strawberryperl.com project) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

> Get-ComputerInfo|select WindowsProductName, WindowsVersion

WindowsProductName WindowsVersion
------------------ --------------
Windows 10 Pro     2009

# the exact commit of the the library using
> cd clip; git log
commit 94693e2414a2c69a8ca16f065240c80a94cc6221 (HEAD -> main, tag: v1.7, origin/main, origin/HEAD)
```

I have no clue what was wrong. I appreciate your help. Thanks.

---

- `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(myproject)

# Disable clip examples and tests
set(CLIP_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "Compile clip examples")
set(CLIP_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "Compile clip tests")

# In case that you have ${PNG_LIBRARY} set to support copy/paste images on Linux
#set(CLIP_X11_PNG_LIBRARY "${PNG_LIBRARY}")

# Add clip subdirectory to compile the library
add_subdirectory(clip)

add_executable(myproject tmp3.cpp)

target_link_libraries(myproject clip)
```

- `tmp3.cpp`

```cpp
#include "clip/clip.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  clip::set_text("Hello World");

  std::string value;
  clip::get_text(value);
  std::cout << value << "\n";
}
```

- cmake configuration output log

```
[main] プロジェクトを構成しています: cpp_dev_02 
[proc] コマンドを実行しています: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\Strawberry\c\bin\gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\Strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe -SC:/pg/cpp_dev_02 -Bc:/pg/cpp_dev_02/build -G "Unix Makefiles"
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] CMake Deprecation Warning at clip/CMakeLists.txt:4 (cmake_minimum_required):
[cmake]   Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
[cmake]   CMake.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
[cmake]   CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Configuring done (0.2s)
[cmake] -- Generating done (0.1s)
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: C:/pg/cpp_dev_02/build
```

- cmake build output log

```
[main] フォルダーのビルド中: cpp_dev_02 all
[build] ビルドを開始しています
[proc] コマンドを実行しています: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/pg/cpp_dev_02/build --config Debug --target all -j 10 --
[build] [ 16%] Building CXX object clip/CMakeFiles/clip.dir/clip_win.cpp.obj
[build] C:/pg/cpp_dev_02/clip/clip_win.cpp:467:19: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
[build]    bi->bV5CSType = LCS_WINDOWS_COLOR_SPACE;
[build]                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] In file included from C:/pg/cpp_dev_02/clip/clip_win.cpp:19:
[build] C:/pg/cpp_dev_02/clip/clip_win_wic.h: In function 'bool clip::win::read_png(const uint8_t*, UINT, clip::image*, clip::image_spec*)':
[build] C:/pg/cpp_dev_02/clip/clip_win_wic.h:210:33: error: 'CLSID_WICPngDecoder2' was not declared in this scope
[build]    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICPngDecoder2,
[build]                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] C:/pg/cpp_dev_02/clip/clip_win_wic.h:210:33: note: suggested alternative: 'CLSID_WICPngDecoder'
[build]    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICPngDecoder2,
[build]                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]                                  CLSID_WICPngDecoder
[build] C:/pg/cpp_dev_02/clip/clip_win_wic.h:214:27: error: 'CLSID_WICPngDecoder1' was not declared in this scope
[build]      hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICPngDecoder1,
[build]                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] C:/pg/cpp_dev_02/clip/clip_win_wic.h:214:27: note: suggested alternative: 'CLSID_WICPngDecoder'
[build]      hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICPngDecoder1,
[build]                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]                            CLSID_WICPngDecoder
[build] gmake.exe[2]: *** [clip/CMakeFiles/clip.dir/build.make:104: clip/CMakeFiles/clip.dir/clip_win.cpp.obj] Error 1
[build] gmake.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:126: clip/CMakeFiles/clip.dir/all] Error 2
[build] gmake.exe: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
[proc] コマンド "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/pg/cpp_dev_02/build --config Debug --target all -j 10 -- はコード 2 で終了しました
[driver] ビルド完了: 00:00:02.763
[build] ビルドが終了コード 2 で終了しました
[main] "undefined" という名前の実行可能ファイルのターゲットを準備できませんでした
```

- Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be an issue pertaining to `CLSID_WICPngDecoder2` and `CLSID_WICPngDecoder1` definition not being found. Going through this GitHub [issue-35](https://github.com/dacap/clip/issues/35) link tells that you are probably using an [old version of MinGW](https://github.com/dacap/clip/issues/35#issuecomment-718124545).

Navigate to the `clip/clip_win_wic.h:210:33` file and line, and check whether you can go to the definition of `CLSID_WICPngDecoder2` and `CLSID_WICPngDecoder1`, if not, that means the required dependencies of the library, especially `windowscodecs` library in your case, are not setup properly.

Comment: also related: https://github.com/dacap/clip/issues/51

Comment: Thanks @ujjwal-raut. Yes, on the file the two lines has an error (e.g. `'CLSID_WICPngDecoder2' was not declared in this scope`). Since `gcc.exe --version` gets `8.3.0` and the issue indicates v10 < is needed, I'm trying to install the latest MinGW from the msys2 site now. I'll update here after completed re-trying.

Comment: Installed msys2, gcc and gdb on it, re-tried and made it to work. Thanks for the help.